# How to increase/decrease 'select' option width after the user wants to select an option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a select box where I hardcode with width. I want the width according to selected text. If text is long then width automatically expand and if text is short then it will be adjust according to it. This is my code.

```css
.post-select {
     border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    }
```

```html
<select id="discoverselect" class="post-select">
        
        <option>All Sports</option>
        <option>OCR</option>
        <option>Triathlon</option>
        <option>Running and Marathon</option>
        <option>Ultramarathon</option>
        <option>Cycling</option>

</select>
```

Comment: There is no easy way to accomplish this. I tried to approach it in a very dirty way, if you want to try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/f7z0e6ab/1/

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you want to adjust the width when the select opens or after choosing an option?

Comment: Thanks GrafiCode Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you can find the length you can change the width according to your characters.
>
> **To find the length**

```
function textWidth(str){
    var span = $("<span>"+str+"</span>");
    $("body").append(span);
    var width = span.width();
    span.remove();
    return width;
    };
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#discoverselect").change(function(){
    $(this).width(textWidth($(this).find("option:selected").text()));
    }).trigger("change");
    });
function textWidth(str){
 var span = $("<span>"+str+"</span>");
    $("body").append(span);
    var width = span.width();
    span.remove();
    return width;
    };
```

```css
.post-select {
     border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="discoverselect" class="post-select">        
        <option>All Sports</option>
        <option>OCR</option>
        <option>Triathlon</option>
        <option>Running and Marathon</option>
        <option>Ultramarathon</option>
        <option>Cycling</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65d9gfxs/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#discoverselect").change(function()
    {
        $(this).width(textWidth($(this).find("option:selected").text())+20);
    }).trigger("change");
});

function textWidth(str)
{
    var span = $("<span style='white-space: nowrap;'>"+str+"</span>");
    $("body").append(span);
    var width = span.width();
    span.remove();
    return width;
};
```